# My list viw is not displaying (Android Studio)

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-listview

Sorry to disturb, but I'm having some problems with my ListView display on Android Studio. I did exactly the same what I saw in this tutorial:[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mja5YoL9Jak). But it's not displaying.
Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    tools:context=".faq">
    <ListView android:id="@+id/faq"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

From xml
and here is what i did in java:

```
    package com.example.mesacerta;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class faq extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_faq);
        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.faq);
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        arrayList.add("Como faço login?");
        arrayList.add("Como cadastrar meu cartão?");
        arrayList.add("Cuidados com a higiene para frequentar um estabelecimento em tempos de Covid");
        arrayList.add("Não recebi a confirmação de pagamento");
        arrayList.add("Como saber se registraram a minha mesa?");
        arrayList.add("Recebi uma cobrança indevida");
        arrayList.add("Como funciona o termômetro digital");
        arrayList.add("Meu cartão não está sendo aceito");
        arrayList.add("Como dividir a conta?");
        arrayList.add("Onde estão meus dado de usuário?");
        arrayList.add("É possível dar uma gorjeta virtual ao garçom?");
        arrayList.add("Quanto são os juros do serviço?");

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


    }
}
```

the output of xml is that:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbROF.png)

Answer (score 0):

I checked this tutorial video and I can tell it works.
(I use minSdkVersion 15. TargetSdkVersion 29.)

I copy & paste your code snippet and even that worked on my phone. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7CTy.jpg)

I can't see your android project and screen, however, I have a feeling your problem connects to your chosen Class name(faq instead of Faq).

I recommend reading about Java class naming conventions.
I pick up some from the [list:](http://dolszewski.com/java/java-class-naming-ultimate-guideline/)

> - Class name should be noun
> - Class name same as filename
> - Class name starts with capital letter

Answer (score 0):

Well , the error will occurs only naming conventions , First your should read   [This Dosc](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

you have to modify code like this ,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { .... }  // use meaningful ClassName
```

when you change activity name , you also Modify `AndroidManiFest.xml` file .